# HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized)

Tags: c#, .net-core, single-sign-on, identityserver4

I am new to IdentityServer4 and I am following this article.
[Protecting an API using Client Credentials](https://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html)

I am getting following error message when trying to authenticate API using client credentials.

***HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).***

below is the code for IdentityServer4's **Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
{
    public IWebHostEnvironment Environment { get; }
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment environment, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Environment = environment;
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        var migrationsAssembly = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;
        var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");


        var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
        {
            options.EmitStaticAudienceClaim = true;
            options.IssuerUri = "https://localhost:5001";
        })
        .AddTestUsers(TestUsers.Users)
        .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
        {
            options.ConfigureDbContext = b => b.UseSqlServer(
                connectionString,
                sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
        })
        .AddOperationalStore(options =>
        {
            options.ConfigureDbContext = b => b.UseSqlServer(
                connectionString,
                sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
        });

        builder.AddDeveloperSigningCredential();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        if (Environment.IsDevelopment()) 
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseIdentityServer();

        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
        });

        if (Configuration["seed"] != null)
        {
            Logger.Information("Seeding data...");
            Data.SeedData.Seed(app);
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

here is the code for IdentityServer4's **Config.cs**

```
public static class Config
{
    public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> IdentityResources =>
        new List<IdentityResource>
        {
            new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
            new IdentityResources.Profile(),
        };

    public static IEnumerable<ApiScope> ApiScopes =>
        new List<ApiScope>
        {
            new ApiScope("InventoryApi", "Inventory Management")
        };

    public static IEnumerable<Client> Clients =>
        new List<Client>
        {
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "CorpLense.Inventory.WebClient",
                ClientSecrets = { new Secret("4678a2df-9a5d-486d-ba66-d97ae503c1a6".Sha256()) },

                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,

                RedirectUris = { "https://localhost:44302/signin-oidc" },// port here should match with sslPort mentioned in launchSetting.json from CorpLense.Inventory.WebClient

                PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://localhost:44302/signout-callback-oidc" },// port here should match with sslPort mentioned in launchSetting.json from CorpLense.Inventory.WebClient

                AllowOfflineAccess = true,

                AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    "InventoryApi" // give this client access to this scope
                }
            }
        };
}
```

here is the code for WebApi's **Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        
        #region Authentication
        services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
        .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
        {
            options.Authority = Configuration["IdentityServerUri"];

            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateAudience = false
            };
        });
        #endregion

        #region Authorization
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("ApiScope", policy =>
            {

                policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser(); 
                policy.RequireClaim("scope", "InventoryApi"); 
            });
        });
        #endregion

        // register controller services
        services.AddControllers()
            .AddFluentValidation(fv =>
            {
                fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<Startup>();
                fv.DisableDataAnnotationsValidation = true;
            });

        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "CorpLense.Inventory.WebApi", Version = "v1" });
            c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Description = "Please Enter Authentication Token",
                Name = "InventoryApi",
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey
            });
        });

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(
            Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
            b => b.MigrationsAssembly("CorpLense.Inventory.WebApi")));


        #region Repositories
        services.AddTransient(typeof(IGenericRepository<>), typeof(GenericRepository<>));
        services.AddTransient<ISiteRepository, SiteRepository>();
        services.AddTransient<IWarehouseRepository, WarehouseRepository>();
        #endregion

        services.AddTransient<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();

        

    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "CorpLense.Inventory.WebApi v1"));
        }
        else
        {
            // register global exception handling service
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");

            // register global status code error page handling service
            app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error/{0}");
        }

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

here is the code for WebClient's **Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

  
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
        })
        .AddCookie(options => 
        {
            options.Cookie.Name = "CorpLense.Inventory.WebClient";
        })
        .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options => 
        {
            options.Authority = Configuration["IdentityServerUri"];

            options.ClientId = "CorpLense.Inventory.WebClient"; 
            options.ClientSecret = "4678a2df-9a5d-486d-ba66-d97ae503c1a6"; 
            options.ResponseType = "code";

            options.SaveTokens = true;

            // ask for required resources
            options.Scope.Clear();
            options.Scope.Add("openid");
            options.Scope.Add("profile");
            options.Scope.Add("InventoryApi");
            options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
        });
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
                    
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

and here is the **Index** method of the WebClient's home controller which is giving me the error.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        // request token
        var accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("Cookies","access_token");
        
        // create client
        var client = new HttpClient();

        // set client's bearer token
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

        // request content
        var content = await client.GetStringAsync("https://localhost:44301/Sites/GetAllSites");

        ViewBag.Json = JArray.Parse(content).ToString(); // PREREQ: Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
        return View();
    }
```

this is the code line that is giving the error.

```
var content = await client.GetStringAsync("https://localhost:44301/Sites/GetAllSites");
```

Comment: What does the log from the API say? why the request was unathorized? also look at the response headers, what does it contain?

Comment: There is nothing reported in Api log. However i have observed that 'var accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("Cookies","access_token");' is returning **null** accessToken.

Comment: also there is no cookie found

Comment: Do you see the tokens in the request, if you use a tool like Fiddler?

Comment: Do you actually have a user object?

Comment: In my code I use HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token").Result to get the access token.

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance for fiddler.. I never used it before. I just installed it and captured the traffic. looks like all requests and responses from the WebClient are not getting any token in the headers. neither do they have any cookies ... I still suspect it has something to do with accessToken getting null in return. without an access token how we expect API to respond?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my applications I use this code to access the tokens:

```
string idToken = HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("id_token").Result ?? "";
string accessToken = HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token").Result ?? "";
```

The strings will be empty if there are no access token.

You can also decorate the method with the attribute, so that you can't even access it if the user is not properly authenticated and authorized:

```
[Authorize]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
}
```

Comment: WOW. it worked. my mistake was that I was not decorating the Index method. Thank you for pointing that out.